# Unsupported Content Type while using curl

Tags: bulk-api, curl

We are currently working on with bulk api to load json data's into salesforce.But unfortunately we are not able to load it and getting error as

> unsupported content type

does salesforce currently support Json post?

The following is the curl command used:

```
curl https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/async/35.0/job/jobid/batch -H "X-SFDC-Session:sessionid" -H "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8" --data-binary @bulk.json
```

> Error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><error
   xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
 <exceptionCode>UnsupportedContentType</exceptionCode>
 <exceptionMessage>Unsupported content type: application/json;charset=UTF-8</exceptionMessage>
```

when we surfed about the error it was mentioned in one of the developer forum as  we have to wait for the next version to make json post work.is it so?or is there any problem with the syntax?suggestions please.Need experts answer please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you point us to the reference of the forum ? And also I would suggest just remove the ';charset=UTF-8'  suffix from content type and tell us if it changes anything

Comment: @karthikselva Still its not working.. salesforce developers forum

Comment: it seems like json is not supported for now even a salesforc documentation says json is supported 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm#

Comment: But I cant find any example which uses json so fo now I will suggest  curl https://instance.salesforce.com/services/async/35.0/job -H "X-SFDC-Session: sessionId" -H "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8" -d @job.txt

Comment: `jobid` has to be an actual job's id, not the literal `jobid`

Comment: @crop1645 I have mentioned session Id and jobid properly  in my code..but not here..

Comment: Pri.  No problem.  Just checking :-)